# Lots of spock tests lead to very long compilation time in eclipse

Tags: spring, groovy, spock

We have lots of tests in 600 groovy files that use Spock.
All testclasses extend from a AbstractSpecification.groovy, that has lots of Service-Classes injected and lots of helper methods to use this classes (Spring, Autowired).

We use Eclipse, and every change to the Abstract class of course leads to a recompilation (Building workspace, Invoking Maven Project Builder). But during the development this recompilation got slower and slower .. now with 600 tests we have to wait aprox. 14 minutes until eclipse has finished, making the test-project almost unusable.

I think, having lots of tests with an Abstract Class is nothing unusual, so I am wondering if people using Spock encountered the same problem. I changed Groovy Version, Plugin Version but nothing helped. Only decreasing the number of testclasses.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Tech Data:
- Eclipse Kepler SR2,  Groovy-Eclipse+Compiler Plugin 2.9.1, Groovy 2.0.7, Spock Version 0.7-groovy-2.0

Comment: Have you done any profiling to see what is causing the slow-down (other than a large number of tests)? Also, does this performance issue only exist in your IDE or does it also happen during your normal build (ant, maven, gradle, etc)?

Comment: Maven build runs just perfect in 40 Seconds (mvn clean install -DskipTests) .. it also uses Groovy-Eclipse compiler to compile both Java and Groovy files. So it has to do with the Eclipse-Groovy-Plugin, right? jvisualvm allocates a lot of ressources while searching through classes during the freeze.

Comment: How long does the maven build take when you don't skip the tests?

Answer (score 3):

In the end, we have translated all Groovy tests to Java. With a lot of testing, profiling etc this was the only solution we have found. This leaves a bitter taste, because Groovy has a lot of advantages, but caused a lot of trouble for us.